# POO Python : 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Tags: python, poo

Realizo un ejercicio en Python la intención es moverme por un espacio de 5x5 pero tengo un error en la simulación de un switch que creen que sea:

```
class Robot():


    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        switcher = {}

    def LE(self):
        if (self.x == 1):
            return "You are in the left limit"
        else:
            self.x -= 1
            return "({},{})".format(self.x, self.y)

    def RI(self):
        if (self.x == 5):
            return "You are in the rigth limit"
        else:
            self.x += 1
            return "({},{})".format(self.x, self.y)

    def UP(self):
        if (self.y == 1):
            return "You are in the up limit"
        else:
            self.y -= 1
            return "({},{})".format(self.x, self.y)

    def DO(self):
        if (self.y == 5):
            return "You are in the down limit"
        else:
            self.y += 1
            return "({},{})".format(self.x, self.y)

    switcher = {
       "le": LE,
       "ri": RI,
       "up": UP,
       "do": DO
    }

    def move(argumen):
        func = switcher.get(argumen, "Invalid Argument")
        return func()

def main():
   player = Robot(1, 1)
   player.move("ri")


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

El error en mención es el siguiente:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "E:\Documentos\robot.py", line 54, in 
>       main()
>
> File "E:\Documentos\robot.py", line 50, in main
>       player.move("ri")
>
> TypeError: move() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

Comment: La definción de  `move()` es incorrecta, debiera ser: `def move(self, argumen):` (te faltó el `self`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tú codigo tiene varios errores:

- Estas pensando que el `switcher = {"le": LE, ...}` es el mismo que `switcher = {}` declarado en el constructor, en el primer caso es un atributo estático o variable de la clase, y en el segundo es una variable local que no es usado y por lo tanto será eliminado.
- La función `move(...)` es un método de la clase por lo que debe de tener como primer parámetro a self.

Asumiendo que quieres seguir usando el atributo estático entonces debes usar lo siguiente:

```
def move(self, argumen):
    func = Robot.switcher.get(argumen, "Invalid Argument")
    return func(self)
```

Como se observa para acceder a switcher debes usar el nombre de la clase(se podria usar tambien self: `self.switcher` pero usar el nombre de la clase hace que el código sea más legible) y para evaluar el método debes pasarle la instancia.

Nota: remueve `switcher = {}` del constructor, es innecesario.

---

Veo que tu intención es usar las funciones mediante el nombre de la función, una mejor solución es usar `getattr(...)`, para ello cambia los nombres de las funciones a los valores de las claves del diccionario:

```
class Robot():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def le(self):
        if self.x == 1:
            return "You are in the left limit"
        else:
            self.x -= 1
            return "({},{})".format(self.x, self.y)

    def ri(self):
        if self.x == 5:
            return "You are in the rigth limit"
        else:
            self.x += 1
            return "({},{})".format(self.x, self.y)

    def up(self):
        if self.y == 1:
            return "You are in the up limit"
        else:
            self.y -= 1
            return "({},{})".format(self.x, self.y)

    def do(self):
        if self.y == 5:
            return "You are in the down limit"
        else:
            self.y += 1
            return "({},{})".format(self.x, self.y)

    def move(self, argumen):
        return getattr(self, argumen)()

def main():
   player = Robot(1, 1)
   print(player.move("ri"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

Answer (score 3):

`move` es definido como un método de instancia (definido dentro de la definición de la clase), como todo método de instancia recibe un primer parámetro obligatorio que es la instancia de la propia clase, que por convención se nombra por `self`, este parámetro es pasado de forma automática cuando se llama al método mediante una instancia (`instancia.method()`). En tu caso `move` se define como:

```
def move(argument)
```

Al no definir el parámetro `self`, cuando haces `player.move("ri")` se le pasa la instancia de la clase de forma automática al primer argumento que es `argument`, además está el parámetro que tu le pasas `"ri"`, por lo que la función recibe dos parámetros cuando solo tiene uno definido, la referencia a `"ri"` no tiene a dónde ir porque `argument` ya fue usado por la referencia a la instancia `player`.

Aparte de esto `swither` debes definirlo o dentro de `move` o mejor en el `__init__` como atributo de instancia, aparte los valores del diccionario son incorrectos, deben ser `key: self.metodo`.

Por último;

```
func = switcher.get(argumen, "Invalid Argument")
return func()
```

va a fallar si la clave no está en el diccionario, si esto ocurre `get` retorna `"Invalid Argument"`, por lo que en la siguiente línea intentas llamar a una cadena:

```
return "Invalid Argument"()
```

lo que puedes hacer es algo así:

```
func = self._switcher.get(argumen)
if func is None:    
    return "Invalid Argument"
return func()
```

---

```
class Robot:

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self._switcher = {
                         "le": self.move_left,
                         "ri": self.move_right,
                         "up": self.move_up,
                         "do": self.move_down,
                         }

    @property 
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, x_value):
        if not  1 <= x_value <= 5:
            raise ValueError("x must be between 1 and 5 (both included)")
        self._x = x_value

    @property 
    def y(self):
        return self._y

    @y.setter
    def y(self, y_value):
        if not  1 <= y_value <= 5:
            raise ValueError("y must be between 1 and 5 (both included)")
        self._y = y_value

    def move_left(self):
        if (self._x == 1):
            return "You are in the left limit"
        else:
            self._x -= 1
            return "({},{})".format(self._x, self._y)

    def move_right(self):
        if (self._x == 5):
            return "You are in the rigth limit"
        else:
            self._x += 1
            return "({},{})".format(self._x, self._y)

    def move_up(self):
        if (self._y == 1):
            return "You are in the up limit"
        else:
            self._y -= 1
            return "({},{})".format(self._x, self._y)

    def move_down(self):
        if (self._y == 5):
            return "You are in the down limit"
        else:
            self._y += 1
            return "({},{})".format(self._x, self._y)

    def move(self, argumen):
        func = self._switcher.get(argumen)
        if func is None:
            return "Invalid Argument"
        return func()


def main():
   player = Robot(1, 1)
   print(player.move("ri"))
   print(player.move("ri"))
   print(player.move("ri"))
   print(player.move("ri"))
   print(player.move("ri"))
   print(player.move("do"))
   print(player.move("up"))
   print(player.move("up"))
   print(player.move("le"))
   print(player.move("fo"))

   player2 = Robot(6, 1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main()
```

He añadido un par de *properties* para validar `x` e `y` en la instanciación y asegurarse que están entre 1 y 5.

La salida para ese `main` es:

> ```
> (2,1)
> (3,1)
> (4,1)
> (5,1)
> You are in the rigth limit
> (5,2)
> (5,1)
> You are in the up limit
> (4,1)
> Invalid Argument
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "test.py", line 84, in <module>
>     main()
>   File "test.py", line 81, in main
>     player2 = Robot(6, 1)
>   File "test.py", line 4, in __init__
>     self.x = x
>   File "test.py", line 20, in x
>     raise ValueError("x must be between 1 and 5 (both included)")
> ValueError: x must be betwen 1 and 5 (both included)
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Además de las correcciones a tu código que te han dado en las otras respuestas, quiero remarcar que cuando haces programación orientada a objetos en python, es importante recordar lo siguiente:

*Al invocar un método de un objeto mediante la sintaxis `objeto.metodo()`, el método en cuestión siempre recibe como primer parámetro el objeto en cuestión, además de todos los demás parámetros que quieras pasarle.*

Esto implica más cosas a tener en cuenta y donde es fácil equivocarse (tarde o temprano a todos nos "muerde" alguno de estos problemas, a mí sobre todo el tercero):

1. Cuando declaras ese método dentro de la clase, debes siempre escribir un parámetro adicional a los que quieras que reciba. Este parámetro ha de ser el primero, y típicamente se llama `self` (aunque realmente podrías llamarlo como quieras, es mejor ceñirse a la norma). Representa al objeto sobre el que estás operando, y es equivalente al `this` de java, si bien en python es forzoso declararlo como primer parámetro.
2. Cuando accedas a un atributo del objeto desde uno de sus métodos, es fundamental poner el nombre del objeto sobre el que operas, es decir, debes hacer por ejemplo: `self.dato = 2`, y no `dato=2`. Esto es diferente a otros lenguajes de programación, donde puedes omitir el `this`.
3. Lo mismo para acceder a otros métodos del objeto desde uno de sus métodos, es decir, debes poner `self.metodo2()`, por ejemplo, y  no `metodo2()` a secas.